# getting notification when someone comments using comments plugin

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-social-plugins, comments

So I have an `iFrame` app on a fan page, which includes the comments plugin. Is there a way I/any admin can receive a notification or email every time someone adds a comment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to `comment.create` event and send the notification to admin in any way you prefer, once comment is created. Facebook itself doesn't provide such functionality.

This may looks like this (I assume Facebook JavaScript SDK is already loaded on page before doing this, read about it in [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on Loading, anyway if you're using Social Comments Plugin it should be loaded already):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.subscribe('comment.create', function(response){
    // Here you need to do a call to some service/script/application
    // to notify your administrator about new comment.
    // I'll use jQuery ajax to call server-side script to illustrate the flow 
    $.post('//hostnamne/path/to/script', {
      "action": "comment created",
      "url_of_page_comment_leaved_on": response.href,
      "id_of_comment_object": response.commentID
    });
  });
</script>
```

In your script located at `http(s?)://hostnamne/path/to/script` you can send a notification to admin, how to do it may vary on way you want it for example if you want to send an email you can use something like this php sample (aging this is just a flow sample, not real code you should use):

```
 <?
   $admin_email = 'root@localhost';

   $commentID = $_REQUEST['id_of_comment_object'];
   $page_href = $_REQUEST['url_of_page_comment_leaved_on'];
   $message = "comment #{$commentID} was leaved on page {$page_href}";

   mail($admin_email, "You have a new comment", $message);
 ?>
```

If you need to track the deletion of comments too you can use `comment.remove` event with similar flow...

Comment: I'm a newbie at this. How do I go about setting that up? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarkNestor, see my updated answer. BTW, Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you'll enjoy it. Please don't forget to "accept" the answer if it was helpful to you by checking mark next to it.

Comment: Please note that there is a very small typo in the code. You opened the string `'You have a new comment"` with a single quote and close it with a double one; not a big problem, in fact, since the code was just a flow sample, as you state.

Comment: @furins, next time you see it, feel free to fix it right away, that's why editing is here ;)

Comment: @JuicyScripter True, but only the author can just change a single char. The minimum change for editing is 6 chars ... I didn't want to add garbage :)