# facebook comments box notification

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments, facebook-comments

Does anyone know how to get notifications everytime someone comments on my website on the facebook comment box?

I've tried this to get an email for each new comment:
 [getting notification when someone comments using comments plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594048/getting-notification-when-someone-comments-using-comments-plugin)

but no luck

I've added myself as a moderator on my app on the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

but still not receiving notification on facebook or on email.

Is there someone who knows how to do this properly?
Thanks.

Comment: I try it too, but no luck. I get notification in my FB page in the notification (picture Earth)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution.

1- Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/

2- Click on "Settings" (top right). A popup will appear.

3- On the first tab, 3rd option, set "Ensable notifications" from "Off" to "On" (as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bUBD.png)